# Optimize SQL query joining when one column is LIKE another column

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
create table DivisionDocs 
(
    RecordID int, 
    division varchar(50), 
    Market1 varchar(25), 
    Market2 varchar(25), 
    Market3 varchar(25), 
    Market4 varchar(25), 
    MarketIsValid varchar(1)
)

insert into DivisionDocs 
values (1, 'Division1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', NULL)
insert into DivisionDocs 
values (2, 'Division1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2', NULL)
insert into DivisionDocs 
values (3, 'Division1', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', NULL)
insert into DivisionDocs 
values (4, 'Division1', 'A5', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', NULL)
insert into DivisionDocs 
values (5, 'Division1', 'ALL', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3', NULL)

create table DivisionValidation 
(
    division varchar(50), 
    Market1 varchar(25), 
    Market2 varchar(25), 
    Market3 varchar(25), 
    Market4 varchar(25)
)

insert into DivisionValidation  
values ('Division1', 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1')
insert into DivisionValidation 
values ('Division1', 'A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2')
insert into DivisionValidation 
values ('Division1', 'A3', 'B3', 'C3', 'D3')
```

I have approximately 5 million rows in `DivisionDocs` and 500K rows in `DivisionValidation`.

In SQL Server, I am trying to validate the `DivisionDocs` against the `DivisionValidation` by comparing the two tables. This is easy with a join query. In this case, `RecordID`'s 4 & 5 are not valid because `Market1` doesn't match:

```
update t1
set MarketIsValid = 'x'
from DivisionDocs t1
join DivisionValidation t2 on t1.division = t2.division
                           and t1.market1 = t2.market1
                           and t1.market2 = t2.market2
                           and t1.market3 = t2.market3
                           and t1.market4 = t2.market4
```

However, sometimes a market# field will contain the word ALL, which basically means it should ALWAYS validate. It basically means it's covering all of that market. So, I'm looking for a way to build this into my update query.

So far I have tried:

```
update t1
set MarketIsValid = 'x'
from DivisionDocs t1
join Divisionvalidation t2 on t1.division = t2.division
                           and t2.market1 like case 
                                                   when t1.market1 = 'ALL' then '%' else t1.market1 end
                           and t2.market2 like case when t1.market2 = 'ALL' then '%' else t1.market2 end
                           and t2.market3 like case when t1.market3 = 'ALL' then '%' else t1.market3 end
                           and t2.market4 like case when t1.market4 = 'ALL' then '%' else t1.market4 end
```

I also tried:

```
update DivisionDocs
set market1 = '%' 
where market1 = 'ALL'

update t1
set MarketIsValid = 'x'
from DivisionDocs t1
join Divisionvalidation t2 on t1.division = t2.division
                           and t2.market1 like t1.market1
                           and t2.market2 like t1.market2
                           and t2.market3 like t1.market3
                           and t2.market4 like t1.market4
```

These both work, but take 8-10 minutes to run. I have a nonclustered indexes on all columns. Just wanted to see if someone had an idea of a smarter way to run this query faster and more efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Try if this works. If it doesn't, update your sample data to include an instance where 'ALL' comes into play.

```
UPDATE dd
SET MarketIsValid = 'x'
FROM DivisionDocs dd
    JOIN DivisionValidation dv
        ON dv.division = dd.division
        AND (dv.market1 = dd.market1 OR dv.Market1 = 'ALL')
        AND (dv.market2 = dd.market2 OR dv.Market1 = 'ALL')
        AND (dv.market3 = dd.market3 OR dv.Market1 = 'ALL')
        AND (dv.market4 = dd.market4 OR dv.Market1 = 'ALL')
;
```

I modified table aliases to have a bit of meaning... t1 and t2 mean nothing to me. I typically use initials of the table as the alias.